# Is it possible to "angularize" data already in the page? (AngularJS + Drupal)

Tags: angularjs, drupal, drupal-7

I have an HTML page that's been generated on the server. It contains data similar to this:

```
<ul>
 <li>Banana</li>
 <li>Apple</li>
 <li>Pear</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to "angularize" (or "post-compile") such data to obtain the same behavior as if the list had been generated with:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

That way, my list would be sortable, filterable, etc.

**Why would I want to do that?! ;-)**

- I'm using Drupal as my page generator and for multiple reasons I'd like to keep it that way (my content is translatable, themable with Drupal's theme functions, etc.)
- Having the initial version of the page fully rendered by the server makes it indexable by search engines. The AngularJS behaviors are mostly just UI enhancements.
- I'd like to avoid an additional roundtrip to the server just to re-transfer the same data.

**Caveats:**

- I'm not just asking how to implement the desired behavior with AngularJS + Drupal (I could expose Drupal's data via an endpoint to which AngularJS would send requests). Instead, I'm asking how to recycle data that's already in the HTML to turn it into an AngularJS model (without resorting to `ngInit`, ideally).
- What I am asking breaks the MVC pattern, I know.

In case you're curious, the site is http://ng-workshop.com/ (it's a collection of AngularJS resources and tutorials).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to provide angular the data is to echo out the php data to the page as a javascript object above the other included scripts on the page.

```
$dbResult = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var php_data = " . json_encode($dbResult) . ";</script>";
```

then somewhere in your angular js code...

```
$scope.items = php_data || [];
```

You may want to place the data in a namespaced javascript object to prevent any kind of stomping on.

Example:

```
PHP -> echo "myApp.page.data =" . json_encode($dbResult) . ";"
Angular -> $scope.items = myApp.page.data || [];
```